# Convert year value to a periodic value in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
    close   year    Day Sin     Day Cos   Month Sin  Month Cos   Hour Sin   Hour Cos
0   278.00  2015    -0.790776   -0.612106   -0.5    -0.866025   -0.707107   0.707107
1   278.14  2015    -0.790776   -0.612106   -0.5    -0.866025   -0.500000   0.866025
2   280.00  2015    -0.790776   -0.612106   -0.5    -0.866025   -0.258819   0.965926
3   280.89  2015    -0.897805   -0.440394   -0.5    -0.866025    0.000000   1.000000
4   280.36  2015    -0.897805   -0.440394   -0.5    -0.866025    0.258819   0.965926
```

I have converted Days, Months and Hours into corresponding Sin and Cosine values since they are periodic/cyclical values which repeat themselves after a certain interval. I did that as follows:

```
import numpy as np
#Month
df1['Month Sin'] = np.sin(2*np.pi*df1.month/12)
df1['Month Cos'] = np.cos(2*np.pi*df1.month/12)

#Hour
df1['Hour Sin'] = np.sin(2*np.pi*df1.hour/24)
df1['Hour Cos'] = np.cos(2*np.pi*df1.hour/24)
```

But I am getting stuck on how to convert `year` value into a meaningful value since `year` is not periodic/cyclical value. It increments as the time progresses. I want to give all the features like year, day sin, day cosine, month sin, month cos etc to my Machine Learning model to predict stock `close` value. Is there anyway to extract some meaningful insight from `year` value so that it may be able to predict accurately stock `close` value, even in the future say 2023, past and present.

Answer (score 1):

@nxe solution is not fully correct. Yes the difference between consecutive months' sin and cos is different, but cos and sin represents a basis for time, hence together, they are equivalent in terms of information and any algorithm is able to understand it.

For a visual representation, see:

https://www.ideadrops.info/post/how-to-encode-cyclic-time

[image]

As you see, sin and cosinus representations are for cycles.
In the end, what we really want to capture with sin/cos, is that Mondays are all the same, even though one Monday happens on the 15th and the other one on the 22nd. Humans understand that but machines cannot unless we give the information in a different format.
Perhaps in your data, you can find some meaningful cycles (at the scale of years) to convert the year into cos and sin.
Otherwise, you cannot convert years into cos and sin.

An alternative to cos/sin representation is simply taking your year column and scaling it by min-max, which keeps the linearity of time and is probably enough for your task.

Finally a last comment, here is a function of mine to add cyclical features to a pandas dataframe:

```
def add_column_cyclical_features(df, col_name_time, period, start_num=0):
    values = 2 * np.pi * (df[col_name_time] - start_num) / period
    kwargs = {f'sin_{col_name_time}': lambda x: np.sin(values),
              f'cos_{col_name_time}': lambda x: np.cos(values)}
    return df.assign(**kwargs).drop(columns=[col_name_time])
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting days and months into sine and cosine values may hinder rather than help you.

1. The difference between consecutive values will differ. The change in the sine or cosine of the months is non-constant. For example, the difference between January's sine value and February's is ~0.36. The same difference for February and March is ~0.13. You'd ideally want these to be the same is you were using month data
2. For days, different months have different numbers of days, so either you use the same spacing and end up with a missing section, or have different gaps between days

What you might want to consider instead is using the unix timestamp

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(year=2015, month=9, day=2, hour=4, minute=45)
dt.timestamp()
```

[`datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) ([`datetime.timestamp` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp))

If there happens to be a periodic nature to the stock, the AI should find it

Comment: I appreciate you answering the question but this is not something I want. I have catered for the 2nd condition in my code. I want the data to look exactly the same, just want to know on how to extract some meaningful information from the year column.